# Broken Code for popup

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a popup that contains tabs, my problem is that they do not show up well in different browsers. Also, the text inside of them cannot be selected. I do not know why.

Here is a working example (text is selectable) http://jsfiddle.net/jdavis78/4nbyA/4/

Here is my code: http://jsfiddle.net/Hunter4854/7wNT8/

Comment: could you be a bit more specific about the cross browser issues?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out, there was an error with the z-index!